# Is it possible to ignore NOT FOR REPLICATION in Visual Studio's Schema Compare?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, replication, merge-replication, schema-compare

I have two environments: dev and test. Dev has a single SQL instance. Test has three which use merge replication.

When I use Schema Compare between dev and test, every table is always flagged as different because the tables in Test have a few replication artifacts:

- A generated unique ID for replication: `[rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [MSmerge_df_rowguid_DDDF85B24558D414B8FD278B2219C33A]`
- The primary key marked as `NOT FOR REPLICATION` (I see there is an option to ignore this in the General tab in Schema Compare Options)
- CONSTRAINT `[repl_identity_range...]` that requires the primary key be within the range assigned to that instance

Is there a way to ignore the rowguid column  and the `repl_identity_range_...` constraint when running a schema compare?

Comment: SQL Compare from Redgate should have that option: [Ignore NOT FOR REPLICATION](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC12/Setting+project+options)

Comment: maybe not what you want but you ought to just add those things to your dev instance - they won't do any harm, and then dev will match test as it should.

Answer (score 2):

[Check `Ignore not for replication`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/ce632e9b-61f5-4663-b587-5245a8c8adcc/schema-compare-and-ignore-replication-artifacts?forum=ssdt) in `General` tab of Options dialog.